# Sorting issue JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I  have to  display a CSV file on the internal web but i have an issue with sorting and Polish characters. For example when I'm sorting by text which one is starting from "Ł" this ones rows going to end of list. Somthing like that:

- AAAA
- BBBB
- ....
- ZZZZ
- ŁŁŁŁ

This is pice of code was I found and I'm using

https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table

Any Ideas  how i  can fix it?

Comment: A little difficult to help you debug your code without any code provided.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any sorting functionality built in to the library you mention.  Please add the sorting code that you are using right now.  It is likely due to a localization insensitive sorting function.  If you show us how you sort, we may be able to help.  We can't unless we see some code in the question.

Comment: Entire code was provided on github. This  funcionality just  not work by default in This pice of code.

Comment: The word "sort" doesn't appear anywhere in the link you provided.

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript? These are different languages. You probably shouldn't use both tags.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use `localeCompare` for locale-sensitive string sorting. Here's the difference:

```js
const chars = ['e', 'ć', 'a', 'r', 'ó', 'o', 'ą', 'ź', 'ż'];

console.log([...chars].sort().join());

const localeSensitiveSortingFn = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b);

console.log([...chars].sort(localeSensitiveSortingFn).join());
```